# Object gets changed even if I do not make any operations with it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Can someone tell me why in the following code snippet the value of `ColumnNames` is changed at the position of the debugger? It takes the same value as `tempColumns` after `tempColumns[k] = modi[i].data[k];`.

```
var addRecords= []; 
var columns = ["Column1","Column2","Column4","Column5"]
var columnNames = {};
var modi = [{
 data: {
  Column1: 'bla'
 }
},{
 data:{
  Column2: 'test'
 }
}];
var tempColumns = {};

for( var n in columns){
 var column = columns[n];
 columnNames[column] = "";
}

for(var i in modi){
 tempColumns = columnNames;
 for(var k in modi[i].data){
  tempColumns[k] = modi[i].data[k];
  debugger;
 }
 addRecords.push(tempColumns);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the object. When you say `tempColumns = columnNames` then they both point to the same memory. with the following method you can make a copy from an object: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

```js
obj = {1:"hi", 2:"by"};

newobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
newobj["1"] = "hello";

console.log(obj);
console.log(newobj);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is happening because you assigned columnNames to tempColumns before your debugger. In javascript values of objects are passed by reference which means that after line:

> tempColumns = columnNames

tempColumns and columnNames point to the same position in memory.